# Strange sorting in Change History with docstrip

Tags: doc

I am slowly moving from writing packages from scratch to using `Doc` and `DocStrip` instead.  Recently I noticed a strange sorting in the "Change History" section of my documents.

I am using version numbers like `v0.1.12`, increasing the last number every time I make a small edit to the `pck.dtx` file.  I also note the changes by using the `\changes{<VERSION>}{<DATE>}{<COMMENT>}` macro accordingly.

Afterwards I run `latex pck.dtx`, `makeindex -s gglo.ist -o pck.gls pck.glo` and `latex pck.dtx` again.  The changes are sorted as follows:

- `v0.1.11`
- `v0.1.12`
- `v0.1.1`
- `v0.1.2`

and so on, which is annoying to me.

Despite changing the version numbering to say `v0.1a`, `v0.1b` ..., or `v0.1.01`, `v0.1.02`, ... is there anything else I could do, to correct the sorting order of the Change History?

Comment: You could modify `\changes`, so it assumes the first argument is always vx.y.z  then make it write out z (at least) padded to two digits

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guessed, there is a switch or another `gglo.ist`, which I don't know of yet?

Comment: I think you are better to do this in the tex layer, harder to do in an ist file as the raw index data has not got an easily sortable form

Comment: @DavidCarlisle being no expert in that matter, I thought, this would be as easy, as---say for example---switching from english to german language :-)  Internally this might everything else but easy, but you guys did so many fantastic jobs, so that outside, it is just a switch :-)